# Create spinning dashed border

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, border

I want to create a spinning dashed border but i have a little problem:
I used something like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="rotate">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate {
        background: red;
        border: 5px solid green;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .rotate:hover {
         -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
         border: 5px dotted blue;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
        from{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to{
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
    }
```

Problem is that i want something like two divs one inside of another (one bigger and one smaller)
like two circles one inside the other.
But if i use this code, it doesn't spin the border only...it spins the div inside it too...

Comment: Clearly you use Chrome only. Have you tried your demo in Firefox? http://jsbin.com/qisir/1/edit :) yep, nice dotted border!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan :Here is the problem,see? I want only one circle spinning at time: http://jsbin.com/xoneruju/5/watch

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I hope that you understand what i want to accomplish here now..

Comment: no cause your link is all messed up, Make sure to lock for further changes (Share -> Click to lock...) and post a link that has the */edit* in the url.

Comment: Immagining what you're trying to accomplish here's my suggestion: Counter-spin the inner circle -or- don't use the inner DIV, but 2 separate DIV overlapped using position absolute. That simple.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry..Here is the link: http://jsbin.com/xoneruju/5/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

**[Chrome example](http://jsbin.com/xoneruju/6/edit)**

Your problem is that your children `DIV` is already inside a `hovered` -> `rotating` `DIV` so...
Use position absolute on non-nested elements:

```
<div class="rotate1"></div>
<div class="rotate2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate1,
.rotate2{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: red;
  border: 5px dashed black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.rotate1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.rotate2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top:100px
}

.rotate1:hover,
.rotate2:hover{
  -webkit-animation: rotate 12s linear infinite;
  border: 5px dashed blue;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from{ -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   }
  to{   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

You don't even need the special classes `1` and `2` for your `.rotate` elements. Just `rotate`.
 [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/xoneruju/7/edit).

Comment: another little problem.. jsbin.com/xoneruju/11/edit?html,css,output ...any ideea why that happens on hover? i made the circles, responsive..

Comment: also I need to welcome you here on StackOverflow and please read the [help] section and also : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I've also left you a comment above with the 10/edit demo